# Saving the values temporarily

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a survey report app, where the user will fill in the data (text and images) but in case he wrote half the report while doing the survey and closed the app to continue later all the data is lost, I am kind of new to programming, I tried to search for a way to do it and found the SQLite but I am not sure of the answer because I don't want to save the data in the app as the report will be sent by e-mail, so as soon as the data is sent I want all the values to be deleted from the app

Comment: If report data is huge then I will recommend you go with **sqlite** and If report data is small then go with **SharedPreferences**. Both are easy to use and after report sent you can easily delete data from them.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this link [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#pref).

You can also use the interface SharedPreferences ([Save key-value data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)).

If you want to save your data in an online Database, take a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), especially [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).

Hope you have all the info.